# папка это файл?

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите человеку который сел читать K&R в 21 веке  )))
Они пишут , что в Unix папка представляет собой файл с которым можно проделать
_open("dirname",...) , а затем собрать статистику по средствам stat(fd,...).
Но у меня Win7 (файл ли там папка ?), а папку я создал, но  результат функции _open -1.
конкретно пытался вот так :
fd = _open("dirname", _S_IREAD, 0);
параметры функции не нашел где почитать про эти всякие _S_IREAD и прочее для винды (наверно ж
это дело отличается в зависимости от операционки ?) .
видимо на таком низком уровне никто уже не работает и никому не интересно.
исходя хотелось бы помощи в следующих вопросах:

1. где почитать про _open для майкрософтных операционок
2. как в моем случае должна выглядить fd = _open("dirname", _S_IREAD, 0); ?? с какими параметрами ?

p.s. папка реально существует там где надо. так как _open отрабатывает с простым текстовым созданным файлом

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw

Comment: В Линукс все это файл и не только папка

Comment: в юникс , а значит и в линуксе это файл. я в этом не сомневаюсь. а вот в винде файл ли ? и как мне тут пользоваться _open ?

Comment: *а вот в винде файл ли ?* А это смотря какое определение понятия "файл" использовать.

Comment: в понимании функции _open !

Comment: "Спецификации файловой системы NTFS закрыты. Это создаёт определённые трудности при реализации её поддержки в продуктах, не принадлежащих фирме Microsoft, например, разработчикам драйверов для свободных операционных систем приходится заниматься обратной разработкой файловой системы NTFS."

Comment: а что значит свободные операционные системы ? у меня win7 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Папка является файлом, в том смысле, что она тоже является блоком информации, к которому можно получить доступ по его имени в файловой системе; и некоторые функции для работы с файлами могут оперировать и папками. Это справедливо практически для всех современных ОС. В структуре NTFS папка также представлена файлом, только, в отличие от обычного файла, она как правило не имеет атрибута $DATA, но имеет атрибут [$INDEX_ROOT](http://ftp.kolibrios.org/users/Asper/docs/NTFS/ntfsdoc.html#attribute_index_root).

Как работает функция _open в Microsoft CRT можно прочитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen?view=vs-2019). Открыть папку с ее помощью в Windows вы не сможете, потому что она не позволяет задать дополнительные флаги и поэтому с ее помощью можно открыть только обычные файлы. Открыть папку можно с помощью функции [CreateFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#directories), передавая флаг FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS. Но напрямую читать байты из папки, как из файла, нельзя: список функций, которые работают с папками, приведен [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-a-handle-to-a-directory). Например, так можно получить время создания папки:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

    HANDLE h = CreateFileW(L"c:\\Test\\",
        GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL
    );

    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION info;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    SYSTEMTIME stLocal;

    if (GetFileInformationByHandle(h, &info) == FALSE) {
        printf("GetFileInformationByHandle Error\n");
    }
    else {
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&info.ftCreationTime, &st);
        SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &st, &stLocal);
        printf(
            "Creation Time: %02u.%02u.%u  %02u:%02u\n", 
            (UINT)stLocal.wDay, (UINT)stLocal.wMonth, 
            (UINT)stLocal.wYear, (UINT)stLocal.wHour, 
            (UINT)stLocal.wMinute
        );
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: спасибо. жаль . задача такова что надо вывести все файлы в каталоге причем, заходя в подкаталоги рекурсивно и там тоже выводим файлы. то есть по сути обход дерева каталогов. предложили пользоваться  FindFirstFile() , однако это другая концепция. а хочется реализовать подобно юнковской реализации.

Comment: а по условию мне надо эту папку открыть по средствам _open (или её аналогом) и присвоится дескриптор . и далее уже разбирать при помощи stat, видимо про этом можно забыть )))

Comment: @АндрейГуренков используйте `<filesystem>` и не мучайтесь ни с `open`, ни с WinAPI